# Connecting MySQL on EC2 to Tableau

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, tableau-api

I used a quick start guide to create a mysql database on EC2 that I can access and query using RStudio. However, I'd like to use Tableau Desktop to visualize the data as well. Tableau can connect to MySQL, but Im not sure how to make it work with EC2. I think I need to use port forwarding. I've Googled extensively and found a few examples but I'm completely new to this and don't know where to begin.

I'm using Terminal on Mac OSX. I'm able to login to SSH and to MySQL once in SSH.

Tableau needs a server, port, user, pass, and initial SQL statement. I'm assuming the initial SQL statement is just "use MyDatabase;"

Comment: Where is Tableau running and where is MySQL running? Are they both in different machines?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tableau is running locally. MySQL is running on EC2.

Comment: If the EC2 instance has a public IP, that would be your server IP address. The standard MySQL port is 3306 - so that's your port. You should ensure that your EC2 instance security group allows 3306 from your IP.

Answer (score 0):

I remember running into this issue awhile ago and found the solution again. I think the main thing to remember is that you have to use the localhost as the address in Tableau after you ssh into EC2 instead of the address of the actual EC2. You also have to setup your ssh to forward the port as you mentioned. Here is how you do that with PuTTY.

In the first screenshot you will see I added 127.0.0.1:3306 as the destination. This is the address of MySQL as setup on your server. I included 9990 as the source port. This is the port that PuTTY will be monitoring for any given calls. Once you have these defined click add and then save your session and connect with your server credentials through PuTTY. Go to Tableau.

[image]

In the second screenshot you will see that I used 127.0.0.1 for the server and 9990 for the port that I defined in PuTTY. You then add the credentials in Tableau that correspond to your MySQL user that is setup on EC2.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response; I'll try this.